# Get compressed byte size after zlib_decode()?

Tags: php, delphi, gzip, zlib

I'm trying to use PHP to parse a custom gzip archive file format that was created in Delphi (not my code!). The format is basically:

```
4-byte integer: count of files in archive

for each compressed file: 
  4-byte integer: filename length [n]
  [n] bytes: filename
  4-byte integer: uncompressed file length [m]
  [????] bytes: gzipped content
```

I can read the file and actually decode the first compressed file correctly by using [zlib_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.zlib-decode.php) with a max uncompressed length of [m] bytes on the remainder of the file after I know the length ([m]), but then I'm stuck because I don't know how far into the substring I should go to find the next filename -- zlib_decode() doesn't return the number of compressed bytes that it processed before stopping. Since this is a custom format, it doesn't seem like I can use the normal [gzopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzopen.php)/[gzread()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzread.php) functions because the entire file isn't compressed (I tried, it doesn't work).

This code works in Delphi because apparently you can pass a file handle back and forth between normal file reading functions and the System.ZLib decoding functions -- you can read [m] uncompressed bytes and the pointer will remain at the last compressed byte -- but PHP doesn't seem to support switching between read-as-normal and read-as-gzip on the fly that way.

Am I missing an obvious way in PHP to deal with a mixed-content file format like this, where metadata and compressed data are stacked together this way? Or am I out of luck without knowing the compressed data length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dirty workaround is to recompress the content of each file as I am able to parse it, use that to calculate the compressed length, and adjust the file pointer in the original file manually as follows:

```
$current_pos = ftell($handle);
$skip_length = strlen(gzencode($uncompressed_text,9,FORCE_DEFLATE));
fseek($handle, $skip_length+$current_pos);
```

This works, but feels very hack-ish. I'd still be open to any better approaches.

EDIT:

Just a note that this eventually failed. However, I was fortunate enough to know in advance the list of expected filenames and I was able to do the following (more reliable since zlib_decode() will decode as much as it can and discard the rest anyway):

```
foreach ($filenames as $thisFilename) {
    $thisPos = strpos($rawData, $thisFilename);
    $gzresult = zlib_decode(substr($rawData, $thisPos + strlen($table) + 8)); // skip 8 bytes for filename size and uncompressed data size, which are useless info.
}
```